# Is it possible to check if 2 APK files are the same, without comparing byte-by-byte (or use algorithms that do it)?

Tags: android, apk

### Background

I want to check if 2 APK files are identical (or have a very high chance of being identical) in the minimal work on the device.

The reason for this, is that I have an app ([**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)) that allows to install apps using APK files, so I want to check if the installed app is already the same as the APK file. This includes using root privilege for background install. So far, what I did was to check the package name and the version code, but I want to know if there is a little better way to perform this check.

### The problem

By "minimal work", I mean minimal reads of the APK file itself. This means that going through all of the bytes of each of the APK files is the most correct way to check if files are identical, but if there is a signature for the APK, that identifies it relatively uniquely, that would be much better.

For example, I know you can do MD5 check on both files, and if it's the same for both, it's a really good chance both are the same, but such an algorithm, along with other similar algorithms (sha1 etc...), go over the entire file, so this is about the same as what I wrote before. It could take a while for large APK files.

### What I've found

What I do know is that comparing the package name and the version number gives a clue about whether the APK files are of the same app and version, but I think that Android-Studio knows more about the APK files, because sometimes it asks if we want to uninstall the installed app even though they have the same version, and it doesn't seem like it takes it a lot of time to ask this.

I could add a file size check too, which should be relatively as fast as the package name and the version number, but maybe there is more ...

Here's a sample code of what I did:

```
public static boolean areApksMostProbablyIdentical(PackageInfo packageInfo, PackageInfo packageInfo2) {
    if (packageInfo == null || packageInfo2 == null)
        return packageInfo == packageInfo2;
    if (!packageInfo.packageName.equals(packageInfo2.packageName))
        return false;
    if (packageInfo.versionCode != packageInfo2.versionCode)
        return false;
    final File file = new File(packageInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
    final File file2 = new File(packageInfo2.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
    if (file.exists() && file2.exists())
        return file.length() == file2.length();
    return true;
}
```

### The question

My question is:

Is it possible to perform a "good-enough" check on both files, avoiding comparing all bytes, to see if 2 APK files are the same?

Comment: Do you mean to do this on your device? Or on a computer?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes On the device. But it could be nice to know about it on the PC too.

Comment: On PC, Android Studio 2.3 provides the APK Analyzer Tool. (But this is used mostly to compare APK of different app versions). More details here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Good to know. Thanks. Though I need to do the check on the device. I've added more information, if that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

> What I do know is that comparing the package name and the version number gives a clue about whether the APK files are of the same app and version,

No it does not. All it tells that both packages used the same values. Anything but that is just pure assumption.

> but I think that Android-Studio knows more about the APK files, because sometimes it asks if we want to uninstall the installed app even though they have the same version, and it doesn't seem like it takes it a lot of time to ask this.

Wow :) All AS knows about APK is in APK. There's no magic. Yet, not sure how you managed to reach your 50K (mostly android based) reputation score and still act like you never heard about the APK signing and all the certificate system used on Android. What usually triggers such uninstallation request dialog to popup is ordinary certificate mismatch, usually release vs debug one.

> Is it possible to perform a "good-enough" check on both files, avoiding comparing all bytes, to see if 2 APK files are the same?

Once you define what `good-enough` and `the same` really means for you in this then **perhaps**, but by using common means of phrases I'd say **no**.

**EDIT**

> The reason for this, is that I have an app (here) that allows to install apps using APK files, so I want to check if the installed app is already the same as the APK file

Then all you need to check if your installed app and the APK files are signed using the same certificate and are using the same `packageId`. If not, this is different app. If this matches, then I'd compare `versionCode` - if the same -> this is the same app. If higler/lower it's downgrade/upgrade. Sure, one can still release different APKs with the same `versionCode` and try to sideload it but I'd say it's not your problem to solve (that's the reason Google Play Store enforects `versionCode` bump on each update). Optionally, if you really got too much spare time  you could compare APK file sizes.

Comment: I know it's pure assumption. Usually though, it means they are the same. About certificates, I actually thought it might be the case, but I also thought I noticed it in other cases. About "good-enough", I mean an equivalant to md5, yet without having to go through the entire file. Maybe is there a way if both were signed using the same signature ? I just want to add as many checks as possible, without having to depend on going through the entire bytes of the files.

Comment: To me you are trying to solve the problem you are unable to fully define. So the question you should clearly answer at first is `what do I need this for?`. And once that is clear you may go further to look for the way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I've updated the question. Look at the background section. Why the downvote though?

Comment: Isn't file size comparison almost instant, as the OS already has the file-system remember the file size of each file each time it gets modified? About packageId, where do I get it? I can't see it in packageInfo and not in its applicationInfo. seeing that 2 APK have the same packageId, what does it mean? Maybe you mean packageName, which I've already mentioned?  Also, how do I get the certificate info?

Comment: `Isn't file size comparison almost instant` - but how does it matter at all? You compares `.apk` sizes. Still this is not value you should draw any conclusion from alone, but combining with the other tests I think it's quite safe to assume this may add the value increasing correctness of final verdict. I mean `package` attribute of `<manifest>` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: About package, this is the package name, which I already check. The file size is actually a good measure because if the package name, the version code and the file size are identical, I would assume that the files are most probably identical, but I wanted to see if there is something that's more like md5 or some signature, that is stored in the APK itself, so that instead of checking all of the bytes of the file, I could just read it instead (together with the other things). What about what you offered of the certificate? How do I get it?